# CompareTo() method gives different results in differnt java versions

Tags: java, collections

I have  the following java collections code.

The main theme is that sorting the "Employee" objects based on their ids,
    but I have one problem here by writing "Collections.sort()" method.
       When "jvm" executes the "Collections.sort(al)",
        java 1.6 gives result as 50 and 60 in compareTo() method ie it calls   e1.compareTo(e2).
     whereas in  java 1.7 gives result as 60 and 50 in compareTo() method ie it calls
    e2.compareTo(e1).
     What actually "this" holds whether e1 or e2.
       What is the actual problem. Is "Jvm" Calling "e2.compareTo(e1)" in
       in   java1.7   and  "e1.compareTo(e2)"  in java1.6 ?

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>
{
 int eid;String name;

Employee(String name,int eid){
    this.name=name;
    this.eid=eid;
   }

  public int compareTo(Employee e) 
{
     int eid1=this.eid;
 int eid2=e.eid;
     System.out.println(eid1);
     System.out.println(eid2);
     System.out.println("-------------");
   if(eid1<eid2)
       return -1;
   if(eid1>eid2)
       return +1;
   else 
       return 0;

}}

public class ForEmployee {

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
   Employee e1=new Employee("raja",50);
   Employee e2=new Employee("rani",60);

    ArrayList<Employee> al=new ArrayList<Employee>();
boolean a=al.add(e1);
boolean b=al.add(e2);

Collections.sort(al); 
   }}
```

Comment: Why is that a problem ? Encapsulation is here to let you not worry about how the sort is really done.

Comment: The sorting algorithm might be implemented differently (it actually is!) on different Java versions. But that doesn't matter, there is no guarantee, in which order the method is called.

Comment: @dystroy: If i know actually whether it calls e2.compareTo(e1)  or e1.compareTo(e2) then only i can write the remaining code.

Comment: is the sorted result anyway the same? if it is, I don't see the problem. If it isn't, I do see the problem.

Comment: The order in which it compares elements is not relevant to the end result.

Comment: Why do you care? As @dystroy says, this is an implementation detail. As long as it works, you don't care -- in fact, you _should not_ care.

Comment: @eis:the result is same ,but how it considers.

Comment: @Bohemian : Bcoz of that order only, "this" variable value changes right?

Comment: @reddy nope. That's OO - `this` is always `this`. It doesn't matter if a is compared to b or visa versa. The contact of `compareTo()` is that it return the comparison of `this` with `that`. The code calling `compareTo()` will use the result as it sees fit.

Answer (score 3):

The end result, sort result, is anyway the same, so the order of the comparisons done within the sorting algorithm should not matter to you.

The internal sorting implementation has changed in between java 6 and 7, so this is why you see the methods called in a different sequence. You should not rely on any sequence within the sort anyway, so if you have a problem with this, you should fix that dependency in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As I had both java 1.6 and 1.7 installed locally I tested your code in both versions and can confirm the results. As with you, this got me curious and I did some googling. I found this interesting blog:

http://dertompson.com/2012/11/23/sort-algorithm-changes-in-java-7/

He talks mostly about the exception you get if you create compareTo methods that depends on which order they are called. But he also mentioned that from 1.6 to 1.7 the default search algorithm is changed from merge sort to tim sort.

I will assume that the exception is added since the new algorithm makes it important to make compareTo methods work independent on which way they are called. After all a logical error is worse than an exception. Your method should work in all cases.